# PHP Regular Expression to find the first youtube link

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, youtube

I'm trying to find an expression to keep only the first youtube link I find in $render variable.

```
$render="some text here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ some text here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ";

$prefix = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
$index = strpos($render, $prefix) + strlen($prefix);
$youtube = substr($render, $index);
$youtube = strtok($youtube,' ');
$regex="@(https):\/\/(www\.)?youtube.com/watch\?v=[\w_-].* *@";
preg_match($string, $render, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$render = preg_replace($regex, "", $render);
$render = substr_replace($render, $matches[0][0], $matches[0][1], 0);
echo $render;
```

What I get

> ```
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ  ://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ
> ```

What I want to get

> ```
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ
> ```

P.S.
The last two links are combined

Comment: Is `$render` a string filled with links, each link separated from the others by a space?

Comment: Yes. They are separated with space in except the last two. They are combined.

Comment: And if you only want the first link, why not simply `explode()` into an array, grab the first element, and confirm that it is a youtube URL ?  If not, grab next and repeat.

Comment: Sorry for not describing correctly what I want. There's possibility of containing and other words except of links. Like:
$render="some text here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ some text here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try limiting how much the regex can match, so it doesn't spill over into the next url:

```
(?:https:\/\/www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[\w_-]{1,11}
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/7wwGRo/2)

```
$render = "some text here youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ some text here youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQhttps://www.youtube.com/...";
preg_match('/(?:https:\/\/www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[\w_-]{1,11}/', $render, $matches);
$render = $matches[0];
echo $render; // => youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ
```

[3v41.org demo](https://3v4l.org/ojk6r)

Comment: No problem @Varkoume, happy to help :) When you have some time, please be sure to check out the StackOverflow [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Using numeric delimiters is not-so-future proof in my opinion, this could work as well:

```
(https):\/\/(www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?v=[\w-].*?(?=(\s|\b|https?))
```

The positive lookahead "(?=(\s|\b|https?))" will match (but not include) a delimiter whitespace or word bound, furthermore it will recognize the beginning of a new URL with http(s) and will not match it, the lazy loading will match less characters up to the end of the link.
I also changed the set because "\w" already includes the underscore.
If tomorrow YT decides to make URLs that are 24 characters you'll be fine anyways, until the latter part still remains included in the set.
This cover all cases of space, newline and even recognize the two URLs that are attached.